# Facebook like actions - Check if URL is liked

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I've read the documentation about like actions, but can't get this to work.

I'm trying to get a status if a logged in user is liking an URL with the Javascript SDK. But doesn't get any progress.

How could this be done?

Below I use this code to "like" an URL.

```
FB.api(
 'me/og.likes',
  'post',
  {
    object: liked_url
  },
  function(response) {
   // handle the response
  }
);
```

HTML

```
<div class="like_button">Like This</div>
```

And when I click the above like button it likes the URL and add a class to the above div, but I want to be able to refresh the page and still have the "liked"-class on the objects that are liked.

Answer (score 0):

I might have picked you up wrong but you could try using this to create your [like button](http://bit.ly/ZteEAo)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm building this in a mobile app, so I need to re-produce the Like-button!

Comment: unfortunately I don't have much experience with mobile development with Facebook so I doubt ill be of little use from here but I wish you luck in finding your answer.